# Run jquery function in SharePoint on load AND change

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, hide, show

I've been using the following jquery to hide a date field when the page loads, then show it if the value of another field is changed to "No." How can I update the script so that, instead of using the change event and waiting for the other field's value to change, it shows/hides the date field based on the other field's value that loaded with the page initially AND hides/shows if the other field's value then changes (in other words, if I open the page and it is already set to No, it shows the date field by default, but then hides it if I change it to Yes; conversely, if I open the page and it's already set to Yes, it hides the date field by default and then shows it if I change it to No). I know I can't use the on('load' event here in place of on('change', but not sure what I CAN do. Any help is appreciated!!!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://**MASKED**"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () 
{ // Get a the choice field 
var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('PrimaryField');
// Hide the target fields in form load
SPUtility.GetSPField('Date Field').Hide();
// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice Field value 
var ShowHideField = function() { 
var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue(); 
// Hide the Date Field field if the selected value is not 'Yes' 
if(selectedFieldValue != 'Yes') { 
SPUtility.GetSPField('Date Field').Hide(); } 
else { SPUtility.GetSPField('Date Field').Show(); } }; 
// attach the function to choice field 
$(choiceField.Dropdown).on('change', ShowHideField); });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You appear to be using `.Hide()` and the syntax for this is `.hide()`. They are case sensitive and must be used properly.

Comment: Thank you @Twisty, but when I change it to lowercase, my code stops working. It has worked fine with the capital H in the past. I just want to change it now from only hiding the field when a user selects a different value to hiding the field if that value was already selected on form load (as well as on change).

Comment: Please indent your code properly to help others help you.

Comment: If I knew how I would. My knowledge of jscript is limited to copying/pasting what others create and reverse-engineering it as needed. I've no idea how to write it myself. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change your code like this:

```
var choiceField = SPUtility.GetSPField('PrimaryField');
// Show/Hide the target fields in form load
if(choiceField.GetValue()!= 'Yes'){
SPUtility.GetSPField('Date Field').Hide();
}
// create a function to show or hide a field based on the selected choice Field value 
var ShowHideField = function() { 
var selectedFieldValue = choiceField.GetValue(); 
// Hide the Date Field field if the selected value is not 'Yes' 
if(selectedFieldValue != 'Yes') { 
SPUtility.GetSPField('Date Field').Hide(); } 
else { SPUtility.GetSPField('Date Field').Show(); } }; 
// attach the function to choice field 
$(choiceField.Dropdown).on('change', ShowHideField); });
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I did try that, but it didn't seem to work unfortunately. In fact, the date field didn't hide at all, no matter what value was loaded in or changed.